# How to connect to a Routerlicious local server?

Tags: fluid-framework

I have followed this guide https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/server/routerlicious and I have set up successfully a Routerlicious server and the gateway https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/server/gateway, but I am having trouble connecting the client to it.
Here is the client code config:

```
...
    const hostUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
    const ordererUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
    const storageUrl = "http://localhost:3000";
    const tenantId = "unused";
    const tenantKey = "unused";
    
    const serviceRouter = new RouterliciousService({
        orderer: ordererUrl,
        storage: storageUrl,
        tenantId: tenantId,
        key: tenantKey,
      });
    const container = await getContainer(
       serviceRouter,
       documented,
       ContainerFactory,
       createNew
     );
...
```

The error is giving me is :
[Buffer is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBdP.png)

I guess it is because of the tenantId and tenantKey. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already got Routerlicious started, if so, jump to the last header. To recap...

### Routerlicious

1. Cloning the [Fluid Framework repository](https://github.com/microsoft/fluidframework),
2. [Installing and starting Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/)
3. Running `npm run start:docker` from the Fluid Framework repo root.

Routerlicious is our name for the reference [Fluid service implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/tree/main/server/routerlicious).

To get Routerlicious started, `npm run start:docker` uses the pre-built [docker containers on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-fluidframework-routerlicious-server). These are prepackaged for you in a [docker-compose file](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/main/server/routerlicious/docker-compose.yml) in the repository.

### Gateway

Gateway is a reference implementation of a Fluid Framework host. Gateway let's you run Fluid containers on a website. More specifically, it's a docker container that runs a web service. That web service delivers web pages with a Fluid Loader on it.

While that's a good option for running *any* Fluid container on one site, it is probably easier to use your strategy. That is... create your own website that connects directly to the service and loads *your* Fluid container.

### Connecting to Routerlicious

To connect to your local Routerlicious instance, you need to know the orderer url, storage url, tenant id, and tenant key. By default, we provide a test local [key in the config](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/8963902d4382e5e927934bf1db9aee61844fda9e/server/routerlicious/packages/routerlicious/config/config.json#L75). The test tenant id is "local" and the test key is "43cfc3fbf04a97c0921fd23ff10f9e4b".